# An internal error occurred during: "Starting JBoss EAP 6.1+". classToLaunch cannot be null?

Tags: jboss

I am getting below error when trying to start Jboss EAP6.1 Server

[image]

Can anyone tell what is the problem here ?

Comment: have you checked [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-16384)?

Comment: No Solution i got so i remove the server from eclipse and download another version and its worked .